# jQuery: loop through JSON results of ASP.NET webservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, web-services

I have an ASP.NET webservice that returns JSON. Now, using jQuery I want to call this webservice and then loop though the results. But how?

I now have this:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
$().ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://www.wunderwedding.com/weddingservice.svc/api/?t=1&cid=1&pid=6&lat=52&lng=5&d=10000&city=nijmegen&field1=0&field2=0&field3=0&field4=0&hasphoto=0&hasvideo=0&minrating=0&lang=nl",
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            // Hide the fake progress indicator graphic.
            $('#mytest').removeClass('loading');
            alert(msg.d);
            // Insert the returned HTML into the <div>.
            $('#mytest').html(msg.d);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets suppose your web method is returning an array of persons so in success method u can loop through it like:

```
$.each(msg.d.Persons, function(index, Value)
{
      firstName = msg.d.Persons[index].FirstName;
});
```

Comment: Ok, but the code I posted doesnt seem to return anything.
Did you try my webservice which is listed in the code example?

Comment: Yeh I checked it and sounds to work fine, the only thing you are missing is that you are calling a webservice out of your domain, so for cross domain calls, you need to include following line:
jQuery.support.cors = true;
put this line before:
$().ready(function () {

Comment: I updated the code in my 1st post. But on the 'alert' I get 'undefined'

Comment: as the response being sent by the webservice doesn't have any object d, so you can try like:
alert(msg.errorCode);
alert(msg.errorString);
alert(msg.hotspots);
these three things are being returned by the webservice, more detailed objects are available in msg.hotspots.

Answer (score -1):

If your webservice returns a JSON then its better to parse it.

Supposing your json is like this:

```
{
    "Status": "ok",
    "Persons": [
        {
            "Name": "John"

        },
        {
            "Name": "Louis"
        }
    ]
}

 success: function (msg) {
        var obj = JSON.parse(msg);

        //get the status value:
        var status = obj.Status;

        //Loop through Persons array:
        var names = {};
        $.each(obj.Persons, function (index, Person) {
            names[index] = Person.Name;
        });


    }
```

To use JSON.parse() you may need this:

https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js